# SSIS Moving data from one place to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I was asked by the company I work for, to create SSIS that will take data from few tables in one data source and change few things in the data, then put it in few tables in the destination.

The main entity is "Person". In the people table, each person has a PersonID.
I need to loop on these records and for each person, take his names from the orders from the orders table, and other data from few other tables.
I know how to take data from one table and just move it to a different table in the destination. What I don't know is how to manipulate the data before dumping it in the destination. Also, how can i get data from few tables for each person id?

I need to be done with this very fast, so if someone can tell me which items in ssis i need to use and how, that will be greate.

Thanks

Comment: You should be a little more specific in your question. That is probably why the downvote (wasn't me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a [few](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx) [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170419.aspx).

Typically it is easy to simply do your joins in SQL before extracting and use that query as the source for extraction.  You can also do data modification in that query.

I would recommend using code in SSIS tasks for only things where SQL is problematic - custom scalar functions which can be quicker in the scripting runtime and handling disparate data sources.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the Data Flow Task.

Use the OledbSource to execute a stored proc that will read, manipulate and return the data you need.

Then you can pass that to either an OleDBDestination or an OleDBCommand that will move that to the destination.